# Is it a feature or a bug that @mentioning the author of an answer in a comment gets removed?

Tags: bug, comments

I asked a question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63934816/find-next-occurrence-of-a-time-like-temporaladjuster), although I don't think it's relevant), which was answered by a user called Sweeper.

I found a small bug in the code provided in the answer, edited the answer and then added a comment elaborating on the edit message. Probably redundant, but felt like a friendly thing to do. I'll delete the comment if Sweeper replies or in a few days. I tried to mention Sweeper, by writing "@Sweeper, having tested this ...". When I was writing the comment, I noticed that the usual autocomplete popup didn't display, but thought nothing of it. When I submitted the comment, however, the "@Sweeper" was removed from the comment, leaving just "having tested this...".

I assume this is at least semi-deliberate, as I understand that there's no need to mention the author of a post when commenting, because they'll be notified anyway, but just silently removing my text seems odd. The reason I included it was because I wanted to be clear that the comment was specifically directed at the author, not a more general point about the answer.

While I understand that the mention is redundant, I'm not sure there's any benefit to removing the text, and there's a definite drawback in that the text no longer says what the user intended. In my case it didn't change the context (although it left me with a lower-case letter at the start of a sentence - yuck!), but I'm sure there are plenty of cases where it would.

Comment: I mean... it can't be a bug, considering it's doing something extra and isn't a side effect of something else. I'd hazard a guess that it was a bandaid to fix some other issue early on and just stuck around.

Comment: @KevinB, OK, I guess we could argue about the definition of the word "bug", but that's not really the point - is it desired functionality? Seems weird and I've never noticed it before, but I guess maybe it's been around for a long time.

Comment: It's been this way for years and it's intentional. OPs always get pinged so the mention is unnecessary.

Comment: @Catija, understood, but just silently removing text seems unhelpful. And it hasn't been the way for that many years - see the last comment on the third answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17699307/service-for-testing-bounced-email-handling) in 2017, it seems the mention text wasn't removed

Comment: It doesn't always get removed. It's only removed if the only people who have commented are a single other user and (optionally) the OP. That example has multiple different commentors. See, I can do it here, @DaveyDaveDave

Comment: Ahh, OK, that makes some sense. Still doesn't seem like great UX, but not something I'll lose any sleep over. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: [feature since 2011](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97099/165773)

Comment: Wow! I think this is the first time I've been mentioned in a meta question. I'm glad it's not some user complaining about me "wrongly" closing their question. :-)

Comment: @Sweeper, great, now I can pointlessly tag you. I'll assume you've seen my comment and have no objection with my edit, so delete it :)

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave I agree this is useless and confusing.  Seems like a lot of dev cycles and a weird way to solve what I assume is the root issue of multiple notifications?